# OpenCV install: deprecation error

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, installation

I would like to use opencv with python, but I think I have a problem with my numpy version. 
How can I make sure that opencv uses the right numpy version?

I did

```
sudo pip install opencv-python
```

And I received this message

```
Installing collected packages: numpy, opencv-python
Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
  Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.8.0rc1
Successfully installed numpy-1.14.5 opencv-python-3.4.1.15
```

Now when I try

```
import cv2
```

I get

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I also updated my numpy version with

```
sudo pip install -U numpy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using both Py2.7 and 3.5 on your machine, make sure numpy is being installed for the correct version by doing either `python3 -m pip install numpy -I`
or `python2 -m pip install numpy -I`

Comment: right I reinstalled numpy and opencv with python3 and now I can import cv2. thanks